# Rails STI and has_many through association not working, SQLException: no such table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, has-many-through, single-table-inheritance

I have the following models:

```
class Test < ApplicationRecord
end

class Exam < Test
end

class Practice < Test
  has_many :relations
  has_many :questions, through: :relations
end

class Relation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :practice
  belongs_to :question
end

class Question < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :relations
  has_many :practices, through: :relations
end
```

And this is my schema:

```
 create_table "questions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "text"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "relations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "practice_id"
    t.integer "question_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["practice_id"], name: "index_relations_on_practice_id"
    t.index ["question_id"], name: "index_relations_on_question_id"
  end

  create_table "tests", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

When I try in rails console:

```
@p = Practice.new
@p.save
@q = Question.new 
@q.save

Practice.last.questions << Question.last
```

I get this error:

```
Question Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions" ORDER BY "questions"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "relations" ("practice_id", "question_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["practice_id", 2], ["question_id", 1], ["created_at", "2017-10-26 06:09:42.581082"], ["updated_at", "2017-10-26 06:09:42.581082"]]
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: main.practices: INSERT INTO "relations" ("practice_id", "question_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

The error is obvious it doesn't find the table `practices` but how can I fix this? I don't understand how to specify to use the table tests, instead of practices. Any help is appreciated

Comment: you will need to create a table 'practices', since it's missing. `rails g migration create_practices`? add fields as necessary

Comment: Nope @kiddorails

Comment: my bad. @Dimitry answer makes sense. I missed the part of STI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should be no `practices` table since `Practice` inherits `Test` and you want to use STI pattern.
I've repeated your models and schema on my machine and it works as expected. So either you have some problems with `SQLite` or with things like `spring`.

Calm down spring with `spring stop` and then try to recreate db with `rails db:reset` and make sure there are no errors.

Moreover I hope it is just example codes and in real life you don't name sql relation as `relations` =)

Comment: Yeah just `relations` is just an example for the sake of clarity.

Comment: Wow that helped! But that was def strange behavior, 
thanks a bunch!
So basically what I did in case anybody needs a recap kill spring via `spring stop`  and recreated the db with `rails db:reset`

Comment: I have encountered the same problem, and solved it by this solution. I am still confused that why need `spring stop`?